# Exception is coming on Non Clustered index in sql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create nonclustered index on table  :

Create nonclustered index 
ON Table_Name(Column_name)
Go

But on execution it shows error :

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name your index. Try

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Foo ON Table(Column);
GO
```